# How to debug activity in jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Tags: jquery

I've got a really complex form with multiple accordions and some checkboxes embedded in the accordion header.

When the user clicks a handler looks to see if anything needs to happen (it doesn't).

However, something is running after the handler so that the checkbox is always checked. Stepping through my code I can see that when the event handler ends the checkbox will be unchecked and at the next proper step it's already checked.

Pause on caught exceptions doesn't do anything.

Essentially the flow is:

1. user clicks
2. event handler runs
3. 4 "step overs" in jquery-3.4.1.min.js with no line of code appearing to be active. Stays unchecked until the last one. Call Stack shows "dispatch" and "v.handle"
4. jQuery mask, does nothing but the checkbox is already checked again.

How do I identify what is happening in Step #3?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Dom Change Breakpoint in the Chrome developer console.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#dom

It is the breakpoint type of Attributes modifications you need to focus on.

> Attributes modifications: Triggered when an attribute is added or
> removed on the currently-selected node, or when an attribute value
> changes.

Also, you can try Event Listener breakpoints at a deeper level.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#event-listeners

Comment: attribute modifications SHOULD have been good but they don't even pick up on the click to uncheck the box, let alone the event that changes it back again.